# The meaning of a phrase someone told me

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image]

I'd like someone to ***explain*** the last sentence to me, **if I was to return only platonic feelings**, I guess it's supposed to be simple but somehow the way it's turned makes it very unclear to me.

Comment: Hello Solène, this question does not fit the posting rules here. You might want to post it (without the image) on the other forum: English Language Learners.

Comment: It's just saying that sometimes you have to lie (or feel you must) to be kind to someone.  (Or sometimes you're just a husband, responding to "Does this dress make my butt look big?")

Comment: The person who wrote that is apparently not a native speaker of English, as "do you consider to be" is not idiomatic.  It could mean "Are you thinking of being my friend" or "Would you like to be my friend" but that's just a guess on my part.  "Platonic feelings" are not expressed by acts of physical intimacy.  It is friendship without sexual relations.  To "return" there means to "respond with".

Answer (score 1):

There are some grammatical mistakes in the original text. I will base my interpretation on an amended version below:

> I'd never lie to you
>
> Or do you consider [yourself?] to be my friend [?]
>
> Cuz then I might possibly have a friend
>
> If i was [were] to return [to] only platonic feelings

It seems like the author is saing, "If you consider us to be friends, then we could be friends, but to do that I would have to change my feelings for you, since 'friends' do not have [romantic feelings](https://www.bing.com/search?q=platonic%20define&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR) for one another." This would imply that the speaker currently has romantic feelings for the addressee.

Comment: I'm not sure that "to" is missing from the last line. It's perfectly acceptable to just "return" feelings in the sense of "reciprocate". I don't think there's an implication in the verse that the couple had a platonic relationship, moved on a romantic one and were, possibly, returning to a platoinc one once the romance had fizzled out.

Comment: @BoldBen Interdasting